# IDA throws "Module <lib> has no names" error after attaching a remote process

Tags: ida

I am using IDA for debugging a remote process. After set `IDA_LIBC_PATH` to a correct libc.so in my android device to resolve IDA multi thread problems, I cannot get a list of export functions of modules; IDA always throws an error "Module  has no names" for system libs.

[image]